# Do we have $f^{-1}(F)=E$ when f is function with domain $E$ and range $F$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a function with domain $E$ and range $F$ ($f\in F^{E}$ ),

- Do we have $\mbox{ Inverse image of } F : f^{-1}(F)=E$

Yes, Indeed

**My Proof 1:**

we have by definition of function $f\in F^{E}$ that is 
$$ \forall x\in E \quad f(x)\in F$$
$$ \mbox{ Inverse image } f^{-1}(F)=\{x\in E \mid f(x)\in F \}$$

**Update:
add proof 2:**

if $\mathrm{im}\,f=f(E)=F$ the result is immediate, since $f$ is surjective. Else $F\setminus{f(E)}\ne\emptyset $ 
and then the family $(f(E),\,F\setminus{f(E)})$ is a partition of $F$ Which give 
$$f^{-1}(F)=f^{-1}\left(f(E)\cup{F\setminus{f(E)}}\right)=f^{-1}\left(f(E)\right)\cup{f^{-1}\left({F\setminus{f(E)}}\right)}=f^{-1}\left(f(E)\right)\cup\emptyset=f^{-1}\left(f(E)\right)$$
The conclusion then follows from this that $E\subset{f^{-1}\left(f(E)\right)}$ hence $f−1(f(E))=E.$

- Is both proof correct

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: of course my question si my proof right

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable will need to chime in, but what if $f^{-1}(y)$ is undefined for some $y\in F$? Intuitively this isn't impossible, but the notation $F^E$ may exclude the possibility.

Comment: Short answer: it is too messy to be understandable. I advise a more verbose approach, and to avoid obscure abuses of notation such as "$f\in F^E\iff \forall x\in E, f(x)\in F$". I think you did not approach the $(\Longleftarrow)$ part at all. Moreover: are there implicit hypothesis on $f$ ?

Comment: update my question so please open it